# In App Purchase working in Windows 10, but not Windows 8.1 or Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, in-app-purchase, windows-8.1, windows-10

I have published a unity app to the store and in app purchases are working perfectly in Windows 10.

However on Win/Phone 8.1, I get an error saying:
Win 8.1 - "Unable to complete purchase. Please try again later"
Win Phone 8.1 - "Can't find item in catalogue. We've looked, but can't find the item you wanted to buy"

Based on these errors, I assumed that my Product id did not match, however I can buy the exact same product in Windows 10, without issue - this to mean shows that the products being sent to the store for purchase are correct.

Has anyone encountered this before or knows what might be going on?

Is there something different that needs to be done in on dev.windows.com in order to make IAP work for Win/Phone 8.1 devices?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? We're experiencing the same issue. :(